Why $g_o^2=g_s$?
In Becker-Becker-Schwarz book on page 85, the author mentions that the string coupling constant $g_s$ (that accompanies each closed-string vertex operator) has a relation to the open string coupling constant $g_o$ as $g_o^2=g_s$. I would appreciate if someone could explain to me why this relation is satisfied. Thanks in advance.
